# how to automatically run a c++ code with different amounts for specific parameters

Tags: c++

I have a code in c++ and I should separately run lots of versions from it by changing the values of two parameters (alpha and cost) I have.

Their versions are as follows:

```
for (int cost = 0; cost <= 100; cost+=5){
     for(float alpha = 0.5; alpha<=2.5; alpha+=0.1){
```

I don't know how to make it happen and I searched a lot for this, but more of them were too complicated or not applicable for me. Thanks in advance for your help.

The structure of my code is kind of simple. I have two functions other than the main function. I am using Visual Studio 2012 in windows 7.

P.S. The computations are not by me, I will pass the exe file of my program to a cluster computer. In overall there should be 400 sets of different versions and I need 5 repetitions of each.

---

Here what I finally found and worked for me:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  for (int cost = 0; cost <= 100; cost+=5){
    for(float alpha = 0.5; alpha<=2.5; alpha+=0.1){     
    string s1 = to_string(cost);
    char const *pchar1 = s1.c_str();
    argv[1] = pchar1;       
    string s2 = to_string(alpha);
    char const *pchar2 = s2.c_str();
    argv[2] = pchar2;
 . . .
```

Comment: `main(int argc, char *argv[])`?

Comment: @bereal I have integer and float variable, could I convert them to char for argv[] ?

Comment: sure, for example, see [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) and [`atof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand exactly what you want, but following may help:

- You have to call `my_f(int argc, const char*argv[])` several times:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      for (int cost = 0; cost <= 100; cost += 5) {
          for (float alpha = 0.5f; alpha <= 2.5f; alpha += 0.1f) {    
              const int myargc = 2;
              const std::string scost = std::to_string(cost);
              const std::string salpha = std::to_string(alpha);
              const char* myargv[] = { scost.c_str(), salpha.c_str() };

              my_f(myargc, myargv);
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- You have to launch `my_a.exe cost alpha`

I suggest to use a shell script to launch an application several time with different parameters.

Else in C++, You have to use `fork`/`exec`...

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, the final code is the thing I lastly figured out and went OK for me.